# Problem in storage space after executing "dconf reset -f /"

Tags: storage, dconf, reset

I executed the command:

```
dconf reset -f /
```

to reset the dash to dock and other extension changes, then when i rebooted my system.

Everything installed from the beginning, starting from user name everything as if i installed a new Ubuntu OS, then i proceeded with the steps ,and all my old files where gone, but my terminal command installations and other applications were available,I started to use , then suddenly i got prompt showing my storage space is full ,i have 78GB for my Ubuntu ,can someone help to recover my old files, as it occupies storage space it looks like it is still in my drive or at least how to get rid of those files  alone(only).

I use Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, Gnome version 3.36

Answer (score 0):

You would have been better placed to run `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/desktop` to reset gnome desktop settings whereas here you've reset more than is required.

In a terminal, take a look at the output of `df -h` which should give you an indication of usage and what data exists. Also try `du -h --max-depth=1 /home` to view the size of your home directory.

Once you've located data, you can either `mv old-files/ new-files/` to move them somewhere else or `rm -r old-files` to delete them. Be aware the remove command is irreversible.

-- BVS

Comment: thank you helping!, i got this when i ran the command  **1.5G /home/suryaks
1.5G /home
**

Comment: Looks like there is data in your home directory. Have you opened it in Nautilus file browser to check? You can also use those same commands to inspect what other data is on the filesystem root.